# How to generate a query which consider data from one table and correspondingly fill 0 for non matching fields in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having 2 tables. t1 and t2.

```
 create table t1  
(   
r1 int,   
n varchar(10)   
);   

create table t2   
(   
r2 int,   
m int  
)
```

the way I populate t1 is

```
r1--- n    
.----------    
1--- abc
```

and t2 is having the following data

```
r2--- m  
.----------  
1---      46  
2---      50   
3---      100
```

I want to display all `r2` values for corresponding r1.
Also mismatching things should also display but with 0.
I wrote a outer join query like this

```
select * from  
t1 right join  
t2  
on t1.r1 = t2.r2
```

The ouput I am getting here is

```
r1------n------r2------m   
.----------------------   
1------   abc---  1--- 45  
null--- null--- 2--- 60  
null--- null--- 3--- 100
```

But what I am expecting is a output like this

```
r1----n----r2----m   
.----------------------   
1---   abc---  1--- 45  
1--- abc--- 2--- 0  
1--- abc--- 3--- 0
```

Could anyone propose a solution to achieve this.
If I adds one more row into t1, say 2---xyz
then the output should be

```
r1----n----r2----m   
.----------------------   
1---   abc---  1--- 45  
1--- abc--- 2--- 0  
1--- abc--- 3--- 0  
2---xyz---1---0  
2---xyz---2---60  
2---xyz---3---0
```

Your help would be much appreciated.

Regards
Anish Antony

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to [CROSS JOIN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php) your tables:

```
SELECT  t1.r1, 
        t1.n, 
        t2.r2, 
        CASE WHEN t1.r1 = t2.r2 THEN t2.m ELSE 0 END AS m
FROM    t1
        CROSS JOIN t2
ORDER BY t1.r1, t2.r2;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/461dee/2)**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use following syntax?

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.r,CASE WHEN t1.r=t2.r THEN t2.m ELSE 0 END as m FROM t1,t2 WHERE t1.r=t2.r OR 1
```

Comment: Isn't this old deprecated syntax?

Comment: you can edit the query by simply adding JOIN between t1 and t2 which I don't think is deprecated.

SELECT t1.*,t2.r,CASE WHEN t1.r=t2.r THEN t2.m ELSE 0 END as m FROM t1 JOIN t2 WHERE t1.r=t2.r OR 1